# Laravel 5 delete MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5 - I have this working on one site but on another I keep getting the error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:
```

I've tried using a js delete handler and I've tried this form:

```
<form action="/order/12" method="POST"> 
   <input type="_method" name="action" value="delete">
   <input type="text" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`|        | GET|HEAD                       | order                                                 | order.index          | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@index                  | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | order/create                                          | order.create         | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@create                 | auth       |
|        | POST                           | order                                                 | order.store          | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store                  | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | order/{order}                                         | order.show           | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@show                   | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | order/{order}/edit                                    | order.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@edit                   | auth       |
|        | PUT                            | order/{order}                                         | order.update         | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@update                 | auth       |
|        | PATCH                          | order/{order}                                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@update                 | auth       |
|        | DELETE                         | order/{order}                                         | order.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@destroy                | auth       |`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not naming the input properly,

change

```
<input type="_method" name="action" value="delete">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

Comment: I think I'm losing my mind - thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

It's some helper function for create delete form :)

```
function delete_form($routeParams , $label = 'Delete'){
  $form = Form::open(['route' => $routeParams, 'method' => 'DELETE']);
  $form .= Form::submit($label , ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']);
  return $form .= Form::close();
}
```